# VS continues on Debug session means memory leak, after closing the application?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

If Visual Studio keeps in Debug session and doesn't stop debugging to switch into the Edit session, could I say there **MUST** be some memory leak in my program after I already closed it from the program itself, especially in C# condition ?

Comment: It usually means that you started a thread that you forgot to terminate.  One whose IsBackground property is *false*.  As always, use the debugger to figure this out.  Debug + Windows + Threads shows you what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. A program running without memory leak can still be running even after a user has asked the program to quit. This can be caused by bugs in the program or library. The bug could be that a thread is still running at the background, or a code is waiting for something that never happens. In Visual Studio, you can press Ctrl+Break or click "Debug -> Break All" to see what code or threads are still running.

But of course from another point of view, you can consider a program that won't quit is leaking memory, since it occupies system memory unless user intervenes and kills it.